# Comparação de datas no PHP

Tags: php, data, formatação

Estou fazendo esse código para comparar a data atual com a data que eu inserir no form, usei essa lógica para fazer isso, mas aparentemente não esta funcionando. O que pode estar errado?

```
<?php 
$data = $_POST['data'];

$nData = getdate();

$dataAno = date('y',strtotime($data));
$dataMes = date('m',strtotime($data));
$dataDia = date('d',strtotime($data));


if($dataAno > $nData['year']){
    echo "Essa data não passou ainda..";

}elseif ($dataAno == $nData['year']){

    if($dataMes > $nData['mon']){
        echo "Essa data não passou ainda..";

    }elseif($dataMes == $nData['mon']){

        if($dataDia > $nData['mday']){
            echo "Essa data não passou ainda...";

        }elseif($dataDia == $nData['mday']){

            echo "Essa data é a data de hoje!!!";
        }echo "Essa data ja passou";
    }

}

?>
```

O formulário está assim:

```
<html>
<form method="post" action="teste.php">
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="date" name="data"><br><br>


    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: e como está vindo a data do formulário?

Comment: seu script tem somente um erro `$dataAno = date('y',strtotime($data));` com `y` minusculo. solução veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos erros no seu código é:

Na linha abaixo te traz o ano com dois digitos, ou seja, `18`

```
$dataAno = date('y',strtotime($data));
```

e você está comparando com `$nData[year]` que retorna `2018`

Portanto, troque o `y` minusculo por `Y` maiúsculo para retornar o ano com 4 digitos

```
$dataAno = date('Y',strtotime($data)); // 2018
```

> As comparações de meses e dias também devem ter seu formato alterado para poder fazer comparação corretamente (vai que ao longo do código se faça uma comparação do tipo `strlen` :).

```
$nData['mon'] //Representação numérica de um mês 1 a 12

$nData['mday'] // Representação numérica do dia do mês 1 a 31
```

portanto,  para fazer comparação com os valores acima, devemos ter

```
// n - representação numérica de um mês, sem zero à esquerda
$dataMes = date('n',strtotime($data));

// j - dia do mês sem zero à esquerda
$dataDia = date('j',strtotime($data));
```

> No mais, seus `if else if` em certas situações ficam devendo

Código corrigido

```
<?php 
if(isset( $_POST['data'])){

    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $nData = getDate();

    $dataAno = date('Y',strtotime($data));
    $dataMes = date('n',strtotime($data));
    $dataDia = date('j',strtotime($data));


    if($dataAno > $nData['year']){
        echo "Essa data não passou ainda..";

    }elseif ($dataAno == $nData['year']){

        if($dataMes > $nData['mon']){
            echo "Essa data não passou ainda..";

        }elseif($dataMes == $nData['mon']){

            if($dataDia > $nData['mday']){
                echo "Essa data não passou ainda...";
            }elseif($dataDia == $nData['mday']){
                echo "Essa data é a data de hoje!!!";
            }else{
                echo "Essa data ja passou";
            }
        }

    }else{
       echo "Essa data ja passou";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Funcionou também!

Answer (score 3):

Isso ja deve funcionar

```
$dataInformada = '2018-04-13';
$dataAtual = date( 'Y-m-d' );
if( $dataInformada < $dataAtual ) {
    echo 'Data informada menor que data atual';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode transformar a data diretamente em um array com a função explode:

```
<?php 

if(isset( $_POST['data'])){

    $data = explode('-' , $_POST['data']);

    $nData = getdate();

    $dataAno = $data[0];
    $dataMes = $data[1];
    $dataDia =$data[2];


    if($dataAno > $nData['year']){
        echo "Essa data não passou ainda..";

    }elseif ($dataAno == $nData['year']){

        if($dataMes > $nData['mon']){
            echo "Essa data não passou ainda..";

        }elseif($dataMes == $nData['mon']){

            if($dataDia > $nData['mday']){
                echo "Essa data não passou ainda...";

            }elseif($dataDia == $nData['mday']){
                echo "Essa data é a data de hoje!!!";
            }
        }

    }

}
?>
<form method="post" >
    <label>Data:</label>
    <input type="date" name="data"><br><br>   
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Existe maneiras mais eficientes e mais econômicas para comparar datas com o PHP. Mas com isso você pode construir seu algorítimo. Acho que essa é a proposta.

Comment: Mesmo assim não imprime nada na tela

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código completo. Teste e vê se funciona.

Comment: Funcionou, mas ai no caso só precisava do if(isset)?

Comment: Não quis interferir no seu algorítimo para verificar os valores. Pois creio que seu objetivo é conseguir cria-lo sozinho.

Comment: @MBoss O isset verifica se a variável post está com com o conteúdo diferente de NULL. Se ela retorna true o código dentro do bloco if é executado.